# Passing meta keywords in php from the previous website?

Tags: php, http-headers, meta-tags

I was wondering if it is possible somehow to pass meta data, such as keywords or descriptions from one website to other by clicking the link. So, we have www.site1.com, click a link on this site and transfer meta tags of it to another website - www.site2.com where we can retrieve them. Say, I am just an owner of site2 and cannot place any external code on site1, except from the link itself. I know this can be done for other things, such as http referrer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

The longer answer is that if you can include JavaScript, then that could modify the link to include extra data in the query string before it is followed.

But, frankly, you might as well use the referer information, run the page at the other end of the URL through an HTML parser, and extract the data that way.

Comment: Precise, good answer. I think I will do it as proposed, but time might be an issue here as I would like to direct the user to a correct site based on the information retrieved from meta tags.